# SEO Impact of ASCII Signature in a Webpage

Tags: seo, comments

I would like to add an ASCII Art signature (about 4000 characters) in a comment at the top of my webpage with my website link and a small strapline in it. This would give people looking at the source a little treat and let them know who built it.

Would there be any impact for SEO in doing this (plus evidence)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are ignored by the search engines so this will have no impact on your SEO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I heard Google only parses a certain amount of characters - does that include the comments or not?

Comment: @Chimoo: Where did you hear that?

Comment: Google will read up to 100k of a file before they stop parsing it and that includes comments. But unless your pages are huge this shouldn't be a problem. If it is, you need to re-evaluate how your content is being presented.

Comment: Please note that the 100kb crawl/download limit only applies to the "Fetch as Googlebot" tool, and robots.txt instructions. Google has stated that the Googlebot fetches much more on [several occasions](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/webmaster-tools/iDKOVdWGF4g).